# Authorize user against resources mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to authorize user against resouces in my MVC 3 project. Is it a good practice to do in the following way?

```
interface IResource
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    bool Authorize(User user);
}

class User
{
    // some logic for user
}

class ResourceA : IResource
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ResourceA(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    bool Authorize(User user)
    {
        // Query database to check if user has permission to the resource
        // return true if the user has, otherwise false
    }
}

class TestController : Controller
{
    // Get details of resource A
    public ActionResult Get(User user, string resourceId)
    {
        IResource resource = new ResourceA(resourceId);
        if (resource.Authorize(user))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            throw HttpException(403, "No permission");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above implementation:

All resources of the website are forced to implement IResource interface.

All requests that interact with resources need to implement authorize code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There many good ways to do it, filters and attributes. Authorize attribute for example check msdn.

Comment: Check Authorize attribute and custom Action filters.

Answer (score 0):

Solution looks good . If you have specific controller and action related to resource , you can also use the ActionFilter , where you can create the custom logic and check and redirect if validation failed. Attributes is also one of the way of central logic system.Solution depends on how your user is going to interact with the resources.